# How to add a variable in a data frame using another variable for indices?

Tags: r

## Data

I have a data frame "veh" with a variable "Tim":

```
> dput(veh$Tim)
c(169.7, 169.8, 169.9, 170, 170.1, 170.2, 170.3, 170.4, 170.5, 
170.6, 170.7, 170.8, 170.9, 171, 171.1, 171.2, 171.3, 171.4, 
171.5, 171.6, 171.7, 171.8, 171.9, 172, 172.1, 172.2, 172.3, 
172.4, 172.5, 172.6, 172.7, 172.8, 172.9, 173, 173.1, 173.2, 
173.3, 173.4, 173.5, 173.6, 173.7, 173.8, 173.9, 174, 174.1, 
174.2, 174.3, 174.4, 174.5, 174.6, 174.7, 174.8, 174.9, 175, 
175.1, 175.2, 175.3, 175.4, 175.5, 175.6, 175.7, 175.8, 175.9, 
176, 176.1, 176.2, 176.3, 176.4, 176.5, 176.6, 176.7, 176.8, 
176.9, 177, 177.1, 177.2, 177.3, 177.4, 177.5, 177.6, 177.7, 
177.8, 177.9, 178, 178.1, 178.2, 178.3, 178.4, 178.5, 178.6, 
178.7, 178.8, 178.9, 179, 179.1, 179.2, 179.3, 179.4, 179.5, 
179.6, 179.7, 179.8, 179.9, 180, 180.1, 180.2, 180.3, 180.4, 
180.5, 180.6, 180.7, 180.8, 180.9, 181, 181.1, 181.2, 181.3, 
181.4, 181.5, 181.6, 181.7, 181.8, 181.9, 182, 182.1, 182.2, 
182.3, 182.4, 182.5, 182.6, 182.7, 182.8, 182.9, 183, 183.1, 
183.2, 183.3, 183.4, 183.5, 183.6, 183.7, 183.8, 183.9, 184, 
184.1, 184.2, 184.3, 184.4, 184.5, 184.6, 184.7, 184.8, 184.9, 
185, 185.1, 185.2)
```

Also, I have a vector "slopezz":

```
> slopezz
 [1] -2.1920  0.7034  0.6113 -1.2540  0.7513  2.3250  0.0791 -0.9713  1.1010  1.9490
[11] -1.4290  2.2500  0.8775
```

and another one-column data frame, "x":

```
> x
            psi
psi1.Tim  171.4
psi2.Tim  171.8
psi3.Tim  175.1
psi4.Tim  175.7
psi5.Tim  176.3
psi6.Tim  177.8
psi7.Tim  178.7
psi8.Tim  180.1
psi9.Tim  181.5
psi10.Tim 182.4
psi11.Tim 183.8
psi12.Tim 184.8
```

## Goal

There are 13 values in the "slopezz" and 12 in `x$psi`. In the data frame "veh", I want to add a new column "slope" that contains the values from "slopezz" but at the indices from `x$psi`.

#### Example:

The first value in "slopezz" is -2.1920 and in `x$psi` is 171.4. `x$psi` corresponds to `veh$Tim`. So, between 169.7 (first value in `veh$Time`) and 171.4, the "slope" variable contains the first value of -2.1920. Then, between 171.4 and 171.8 the second value of slope, 0.7034. And so on.

## What I have tried

I can successfully create the new column by using `ifelse` and putting in the values of `x$psi` and "slopezz" manually.

## Example:

```
library(dplyr)
veh <- veh %>% 
  mutate(slope = ifelse(Tim<=171.4,slopezz[1], 
                           ifelse(Tim>171.4 & Tim<=171.8, slopezz[2], ....
```

Code was long, so not putting the entire thing here.

But is there a better method where I don't have to manually put the `Tim` values taken from `x$psi`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need joins, and something like `tidyr::fill`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

x %>% mutate(slopezz = slopezz[1:n()]) %>% 
    right_join(veh, by = c('psi' = 'Tim')) %>% 
    fill(slopezz, .direction = 'up')
#     psi slopezz
# 1 169.7 -2.1920
# 2 169.8 -2.1920
# 3 169.9 -2.1920
# 4 170.0 -2.1920
# 5 170.1 -2.1920
# 6 170.2 -2.1920
# .   ...     ...
```

Note that this will leave the last four values as `NA` as you're `fill`ing up. If you want to then `fill` down, just add on `%>% fill(slopezz)`.

---

#### Data

```
x <- structure(list(psi = c(171.4, 171.8, 175.1, 175.7, 176.3, 177.8, 
               178.7, 180.1, 181.5, 182.4, 183.8, 184.8)), .Names = "psi", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))

slopezz <- c(-2.192, 0.7034, 0.6113, -1.254, 0.7513, 2.325, 0.0791, -0.9713, 
             1.101, 1.949, -1.429, 2.25, 0.8775)

veh <- structure(list(Tim = c(169.7, 169.8, 169.9, 170, 170.1, 170.2, 
                 170.3, 170.4, 170.5, 170.6, 170.7, 170.8, 170.9, 171, 171.1, 
                 171.2, 171.3, 171.4, 171.5, 171.6, 171.7, 171.8, 171.9, 172, 
                 172.1, 172.2, 172.3, 172.4, 172.5, 172.6, 172.7, 172.8, 172.9,  
                 173, 173.1, 173.2, 173.3, 173.4, 173.5, 173.6, 173.7, 173.8, 
                 173.9, 174, 174.1, 174.2, 174.3, 174.4, 174.5, 174.6, 174.7, 
                 174.8, 174.9, 175, 175.1, 175.2, 175.3, 175.4, 175.5, 175.6, 
                 175.7, 175.8, 175.9, 176, 176.1, 176.2, 176.3, 176.4, 176.5, 
                 176.6, 176.7, 176.8, 176.9, 177, 177.1, 177.2, 177.3, 177.4, 
                 177.5, 177.6, 177.7, 177.8, 177.9, 178, 178.1, 178.2, 178.3, 
                 178.4, 178.5, 178.6, 178.7, 178.8, 178.9, 179, 179.1, 179.2, 
                 179.3, 179.4, 179.5, 179.6, 179.7, 179.8, 179.9, 180, 180.1, 
                 180.2, 180.3, 180.4, 180.5, 180.6, 180.7, 180.8, 180.9, 181, 
                 181.1, 181.2, 181.3, 181.4, 181.5, 181.6, 181.7, 181.8, 181.9,  
                 182, 182.1, 182.2, 182.3, 182.4, 182.5, 182.6, 182.7, 182.8, 
                 182.9, 183, 183.1, 183.2, 183.3, 183.4, 183.5, 183.6, 183.7, 
                 183.8, 183.9, 184, 184.1, 184.2, 184.3, 184.4, 184.5, 184.6, 
                 184.7, 184.8, 184.9, 185, 185.1, 185.2)), .Names = "Tim", row.names = c(NA, 
                 -156L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 3):

You had the right idea using `dput()` for `veh$Tim`; it would have helped had you used it for `slopezz` and `x` as well.

Here's a two line solution (where `ix` is a temporary index variable):

```
ix <- sapply(veh$Time, function(z) which.max(z <= c(x$psi, Inf)))
veh$slope <- slopezz[ix]
```

You were a bit ambiguous about what value of `slopezz` to use when, for example, `veh$Tim` equals 171.4. The code above uses intervals closed on the right.

Comment: In the interests of full disclosure, I don't think this is a good approach for big data frames. Internally, it will do some loops for all index values when they could be cut short, particularly if the input data are already sorted chronologically. For small data frames like this one, the inefficiency is unlikely to matter.

Comment: Thanks. You are correct that this code is not good for a big data set. I applied it for a data set of size 150 MB, using `for loop`. The resulting data frame is 59.4 GB!

Comment: The inefficiency in the code should manifest in run time, not memory use. If you are saying that the data frame veh went from 150 MB to 59.4 GB just by adding the veh$Time field, that should not be possible. I did not include code to remove the ix vector once you are done with it ('rm(ix)'), but ix should not be all that big either.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using the cut function from base R.
The data:

```
veh<-data.frame(Tim=c(169.7, 169.8, 169.9, 170, 170.1, 170.2, 170.3, 170.4, 170.5, 
                      170.6, 170.7, 170.8, 170.9, 171, 171.1, 171.2, 171.3, 171.4, 
                      171.5, 171.6, 171.7, 171.8, 171.9, 172, 172.1, 172.2, 172.3, 
                      172.4, 172.5, 172.6, 172.7, 172.8, 172.9, 173, 173.1, 173.2, 
                      173.3, 173.4, 173.5, 173.6, 173.7, 173.8, 173.9, 174, 174.1, 
                      174.2, 174.3, 174.4, 174.5, 174.6, 174.7, 174.8, 174.9, 175, 
                      175.1, 175.2, 175.3, 175.4, 175.5, 175.6, 175.7, 175.8, 175.9, 
                      176, 176.1, 176.2, 176.3, 176.4, 176.5, 176.6, 176.7, 176.8, 
                      176.9, 177, 177.1, 177.2, 177.3, 177.4, 177.5, 177.6, 177.7, 
                      177.8, 177.9, 178, 178.1, 178.2, 178.3, 178.4, 178.5, 178.6, 
                      178.7, 178.8, 178.9, 179, 179.1, 179.2, 179.3, 179.4, 179.5, 
                      179.6, 179.7, 179.8, 179.9, 180, 180.1, 180.2, 180.3, 180.4, 
                      180.5, 180.6, 180.7, 180.8, 180.9, 181, 181.1, 181.2, 181.3, 
                      181.4, 181.5, 181.6, 181.7, 181.8, 181.9, 182, 182.1, 182.2, 
                      182.3, 182.4, 182.5, 182.6, 182.7, 182.8, 182.9, 183, 183.1, 
                      183.2, 183.3, 183.4, 183.5, 183.6, 183.7, 183.8, 183.9, 184, 
                      184.1, 184.2, 184.3, 184.4, 184.5, 184.6, 184.7, 184.8, 184.9, 
                      185, 185.1, 185.2))
slopezz<-c(-2.1920,  0.7034,  0.6113, -1.2540,  0.7513,  2.3250,  0.0791, -0.9713,
           1.1010,  1.9490, -1.4290,  2.2500,  0.8775)
x<-c(171.4, 171.8,  175.1,  175.7,  176.3,  177.8,  178.7,  180.1,  181.5,
      182.4, 183.8, 184.8)
```

Now define x to encompass the entire range of Tim:

```
x<-c(0,x,200)
veh$slope<-slopezz[cut(veh$Tim, breaks=x)]
```

The final dataframe for this example will be the column Tim and the new column slope.

Answer (score 1):

A brute force way would be

```
veh$slope = rep(slopes[1], length(veh$Tim))
for (j in 1:12) veh$slope[ veh$Tim>x$psi[j] ] = slopes[j+1]
```