# Alternative to for loop for a data frame in r

Tags: r

## EDIT:

#### Data Description

`Vehicle.ID2` is a unique identifier for a vehicle (car, truck or motorcycle). The movement of each vehicle was recorded over `Time` which is available in the `Time` column in the `dt2` data frame. The original `dt2` has more than 40 variables including speeds, accelerations, etc. in every  `Time` frame. With the speed and Time, I used the `segmented` package in r to estimate the `slopez` (smoothed acceleration) for each `Vehicle.ID2`. These `slopez` are constant between particular points in `Time`, called as breakpoints, `bp`. For clarification I am including the 3 data sets for 2 unique `Vehicle.ID2`s:

```
dt2 <- structure(list(Vehicle.ID2 = c("6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", 
"6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", 
"6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", 
"6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", 
"6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", 
"6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", 
"6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", 
"6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", 
"6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", 
"6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", 
"6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", 
"6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", 
"6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", 
"6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", 
"6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", 
"6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", 
"6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", 
"6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", 
"6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", 
"6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", 
"6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", 
"6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", 
"6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", 
"6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", 
"6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", 
"6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", 
"6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", 
"6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", 
"6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", 
"6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", 
"6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", 
"6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "8-5", "8-5", 
"8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", 
"8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", 
"8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", 
"8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", 
"8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", 
"8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", 
"8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", 
"8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", 
"8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", 
"8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", 
"8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", 
"8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", 
"8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", 
"8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", 
"8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", 
"8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", 
"8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", 
"8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", 
"8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", 
"8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", 
"8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", 
"8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", 
"8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", 
"8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", 
"8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", 
"8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", 
"8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", 
"8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", 
"8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", 
"8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", 
"8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", 
"8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", 
"8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", 
"8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", 
"8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", 
"8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", 
"8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", 
"8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", 
"8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", 
"8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", 
"8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", 
"8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", 
"8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", 
"8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", 
"8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", 
"8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", 
"8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", 
"8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5"), Time = c(14.1, 14.2, 
14.3, 14.4, 14.5, 14.6, 14.7, 14.8, 14.9, 15, 15.1, 15.2, 15.3, 
15.4, 16.8, 16.9, 17, 17.1, 17.2, 17.3, 17.4, 17.5, 17.6, 17.7, 
17.8, 17.9, 18, 18.1, 18.2, 22.5, 22.6, 22.7, 22.9, 23, 23.1, 
23.2, 23.3, 23.4, 23.5, 23.6, 23.7, 23.8, 23.9, 24, 24.1, 24.2, 
24.3, 24.4, 24.5, 24.6, 24.7, 24.8, 24.9, 25, 25.1, 25.2, 25.3, 
25.4, 25.5, 25.6, 25.7, 25.8, 25.9, 26, 26.1, 26.2, 26.3, 26.4, 
26.5, 26.6, 26.7, 26.8, 26.9, 27, 27.1, 27.2, 27.3, 27.4, 27.5, 
27.6, 27.7, 27.8, 27.9, 28, 28.1, 28.2, 28.3, 28.4, 28.5, 28.6, 
28.7, 28.8, 28.9, 29, 29.1, 29.2, 29.3, 29.4, 29.5, 29.6, 29.7, 
29.8, 29.9, 30, 30.1, 30.2, 30.3, 30.4, 30.5, 30.6, 30.7, 30.8, 
30.9, 31, 31.1, 31.2, 31.3, 31.4, 31.5, 31.6, 31.7, 31.8, 31.9, 
32, 32.1, 32.2, 32.3, 32.4, 32.5, 32.6, 32.7, 32.8, 32.9, 33, 
33.1, 33.2, 33.3, 33.4, 33.5, 33.6, 33.7, 33.8, 33.9, 34, 34.1, 
34.2, 34.3, 34.4, 34.5, 34.6, 34.7, 34.8, 34.9, 35, 35.1, 35.2, 
35.3, 35.4, 35.5, 35.6, 35.7, 35.8, 35.9, 36, 36.1, 36.2, 36.3, 
36.4, 36.5, 36.6, 36.7, 36.8, 36.9, 37, 37.1, 37.2, 37.3, 37.4, 
37.5, 37.6, 37.7, 37.8, 37.9, 38, 38.1, 38.2, 38.3, 38.4, 38.5, 
38.6, 38.7, 38.8, 38.9, 39, 39.1, 39.2, 39.3, 39.4, 39.5, 39.6, 
39.7, 39.8, 39.9, 40, 40.1, 40.2, 40.3, 40.4, 40.5, 40.6, 40.7, 
40.8, 40.9, 41, 41.1, 41.2, 41.3, 41.4, 41.5, 41.6, 41.7, 41.8, 
41.9, 42, 42.1, 42.2, 42.3, 42.4, 42.5, 42.6, 42.7, 42.8, 42.9, 
43, 43.1, 43.2, 43.3, 43.4, 43.5, 43.6, 43.7, 43.8, 43.9, 44, 
44.1, 44.2, 44.3, 44.4, 44.5, 44.6, 44.7, 44.8, 44.9, 45, 45.1, 
45.2, 45.3, 45.4, 45.5, 45.6, 45.7, 45.8, 45.9, 46, 46.1, 46.2, 
46.3, 46.4, 46.5, 46.6, 46.7, 46.8, 46.9, 47, 47.1, 47.2, 47.3, 
47.4, 47.5, 47.6, 47.7, 47.8, 2.9, 3, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5, 
3.6, 3.7, 3.8, 3.9, 4, 4.1, 4.2, 4.3, 4.4, 4.5, 4.6, 4.7, 4.8, 
4.9, 5, 5.1, 5.2, 5.3, 5.4, 5.5, 5.6, 5.7, 5.8, 5.9, 6, 6.1, 
6.2, 6.3, 6.4, 6.5, 6.6, 6.7, 6.8, 6.9, 7, 7.1, 7.2, 7.3, 7.4, 
7.5, 7.6, 7.7, 7.8, 7.9, 8, 8.1, 8.2, 8.3, 8.4, 8.5, 8.6, 8.7, 
8.8, 8.9, 9, 9.1, 9.2, 9.3, 9.4, 9.5, 9.6, 9.7, 9.8, 9.9, 10, 
10.1, 10.2, 10.3, 10.4, 10.5, 10.6, 10.7, 10.8, 10.9, 11, 11.1, 
11.2, 11.3, 11.4, 11.5, 11.6, 11.7, 11.8, 11.9, 12, 12.1, 12.2, 
12.3, 12.4, 12.5, 12.6, 12.7, 12.8, 12.9, 13, 13.1, 13.2, 13.3, 
13.4, 13.5, 13.6, 13.7, 13.8, 13.9, 14, 14.1, 14.2, 14.3, 14.4, 
14.5, 14.6, 14.7, 14.8, 14.9, 15, 15.1, 15.2, 15.3, 15.4, 15.5, 
15.6, 15.7, 15.8, 15.9, 16, 16.1, 16.2, 16.3, 16.4, 16.5, 16.6, 
16.7, 16.8, 16.9, 17, 17.1, 17.2, 17.3, 17.4, 17.5, 17.6, 17.7, 
17.8, 17.9, 18, 18.1, 18.2, 18.3, 18.4, 18.5, 18.6, 18.7, 18.8, 
18.9, 19, 19.1, 19.2, 19.3, 19.4, 19.5, 19.6, 19.7, 19.8, 19.9, 
20, 20.1, 20.2, 20.3, 20.4, 20.5, 20.6, 20.7, 20.8, 20.9, 21, 
21.1, 21.2, 21.3, 21.4, 21.5, 21.6, 21.7, 21.8, 21.9, 22, 22.1, 
22.2, 22.3, 22.4, 22.5, 22.6, 22.7, 22.8, 22.9, 23, 23.1, 23.2, 
23.3, 23.4, 23.5, 23.6, 23.7, 23.8, 23.9, 24, 24.1, 24.2, 24.3, 
24.4, 24.5, 24.6, 24.7, 24.8, 24.9, 25, 25.1, 25.2, 25.3, 25.4, 
25.5, 25.6, 25.7, 25.8, 25.9, 26, 26.1, 26.2, 26.3, 26.4, 26.5, 
26.6, 26.7, 26.8, 26.9, 27, 27.1, 27.2, 27.3, 27.4, 27.5, 27.6, 
27.7, 27.8, 27.9, 28, 28.1, 28.2, 28.3, 28.4, 28.5, 28.6, 28.7, 
28.8, 28.9, 29, 29.1, 29.2, 29.3, 29.4, 29.5, 29.6, 29.7, 29.8, 
29.9, 30, 30.1, 30.2, 30.3, 30.4, 30.5, 30.6, 30.7, 30.8, 30.9, 
31, 31.1, 31.2, 31.3, 31.4, 31.5, 31.6, 31.7, 31.8, 31.9, 32, 
32.1, 32.2, 32.3, 32.4, 32.5, 32.6, 32.7, 32.8, 32.9, 33, 33.1, 
33.2, 33.3, 33.4, 33.5, 33.6, 33.7, 33.8, 33.9, 34, 34.1, 34.2, 
34.3, 34.4, 34.5, 34.6, 34.7, 34.8, 34.9, 35, 35.1, 35.2, 35.3, 
35.4, 35.5, 35.6, 35.7, 35.8, 35.9, 36, 36.1, 36.2, 36.3, 36.4, 
36.5, 36.6, 36.7, 36.8, 36.9, 37, 37.1, 37.2, 37.3, 37.4, 37.5, 
37.6, 37.7, 37.8, 37.9, 38, 38.1, 38.2, 38.3, 38.4, 38.5, 38.6, 
38.7, 38.8, 38.9, 39, 39.1, 39.2, 39.3, 39.4, 39.5, 39.6, 39.7, 
39.8, 39.9, 40, 40.1, 40.2, 40.3, 40.4, 40.5, 40.6, 40.7, 40.8, 
40.9, 41, 41.1, 41.2, 41.3, 41.4, 41.5, 41.6, 41.7, 41.8, 41.9, 
42, 42.1, 42.2, 42.3, 42.4, 42.5, 42.6, 42.7, 42.8, 42.9, 43, 
43.1, 43.2, 43.3, 43.4, 43.5, 43.6, 43.7, 43.8, 43.9, 44, 44.1, 
44.2, 44.3, 44.4, 44.5, 44.6, 44.7, 44.8, 44.9, 45, 45.1, 45.2, 
45.3, 45.4, 45.5, 45.6, 45.7, 45.8, 45.9)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -713L), .Names = c("Vehicle.ID2", 
"Time"))

dt_slopez <- structure(list(Vehicle.ID2 = c("6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", 
"6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", 
"8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", 
"8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5"), slopez = c(-1.707, 
-1.424, 1.414, -0.1184, 0.199, 0.6955, 0.6875, 0.1744, 0.6189, 
0.06681, 1.606, 2.348, 0.632, 0.295, -2.298, 1.918, -0.7171, 
-1.506, 1.057, 0.1312, 1.589, 0.3844, 2.314, -0.6393, 2.054, 
0.8238, 0.225, 0.7208, 0.489, 0.0303)), .Names = c("Vehicle.ID2", 
"slopez"), class = c("tbl_dt", "tbl", "data.table", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -30L))

dt_bp  <- structure(list(Vehicle.ID2 = c("6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", 
"6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "6-4", "8-5", 
"8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", 
"8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5", "8-5"), bp = c(15, 17.3, 18.2, 24.3, 
28.4, 33, 38.1, 39.4, 41.3, 41.8, 43.4, 44.2, 45.7, 7.1, 9.4, 
11.4, 13.1, 15.3, 24.3, 26.5, 30.4, 34.1, 36.8, 39.9, 40.4, 40.9, 
41.8, 44.3)), .Names = c("Vehicle.ID2", "bp"), class = c("tbl_dt", 
"tbl", "data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -28L))
```

#### Objective

`bp` are the breakpoints and I want to find these points in the `Time` column in the `dt2` data frame. Then, I want to create a new column `slope` in `dt2` which takes the values of `slopez` between the particular `Time`s. For example, for the `Vehicle.ID2=="6-4"`, the first `bp` is 15 and the first entry in `Time` is 14.1. This means that between 14.1 and 15 the `slope` should be the first value in the `slopez` (for this `Vehicle.ID2`) i.e. -1.707; then between 15 and 17.3 it should be -1.424, and so on.
I asked this question before and got the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37261025/how-to-add-a-variable-in-a-data-frame-using-another-variable-for-indices).

## for loop to apply the function

In the complete data sets there are multiple `Vehicle.ID2`s. The following code works:

```
datalist = list()
for (i in unique(dt2$Vehicle.ID2)){
  veh <- subset(dt2, Vehicle.ID2==i)
  ix <- sapply(veh$Time, function(z) which.max(z < c(dt_bp[dt_bp$Vehicle.ID2==i,]$bp, Inf)))
  veh$slope <- dt_slopez[dt_slopez$Vehicle.ID2==i,]$slopez[ix]
  datalist[[i]] <- veh
}
dt2 <- do.call(rbind, datalist)
```

### Problems

The above code does achieve the objective both for these sample data and the original data (about 150 MB in size). But it is slow for the original data. Also, the final data set `dt2` (with multiple `Vehicle.ID2`s) is unacceptably big, 59.4 GB!
For these sample data, it is not a problem. But for the original data set it is too much. What alternatives to `for loop` can I use to achieve the same objective so that it is fast and final data set is small in size? Also, am I using the `for loop` wrong, which causes the final data to be this big?

Comment: why aren't you using `lapply` for the main loop too ? If you have multi processor computers, you can also consider `foreach` package

Comment: If the final result is what you want, then its size, 59.4 GB, will not change if you change the method. You will need to reduce what you want in the result to reduce the size of the result.

Comment: @Gregor, I am only estimating a new variable, `slope`. The size shouldn't increase that much, I think.

Comment: One extra numeric column is not taking up 59.25 GB of space. What else is in your result to take up all that memory? What are the dimensions and data type of your `dt2` and do they make sense based on your input?

Comment: I am not understanding the purpose of this statement: "sapply(veh$Time, function(z) which.max(z < c(dt_bp[dt_bp$Vehicle.ID2==i,]$bp, Inf)))"  The sapply is returning 1 for every value of veh$Time

Comment: It would be very helpful to clearly explain what the objective of your function is, and what each of the inputs represent. Hard to simplify without this, and your example does not provide enough complexity to really understand what you are trying to calculate

Comment: Agree with Chris; at a first glance, you should use data.table and merge your data. Then it is a matter of treating mergeData with a `by`.

Comment: I now think I understand what you are trying to do. That said, your data is not well set up for this - You should set up a table that looks like [vehicle, min time, max time, slopez], and then merge that to your dt2. Post the first table here and we can help you (the likely solution will be a roll join).

Comment: Note that you will need to make a call of whether your min time or max time is inclusive of endpoints or not i.e. is it [ ) or ( ] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an attempt using base R's cut command.

```
dt2$slope<-NA  #add placeholder column onto dataframe

for (i in unique(dt2$Vehicle.ID2)){
  #add higher and lower limt for the cut limits
  breaks<-c(0.0, dt_bp$bp[dt_bp$Vehicle.ID2==i], Inf) 
  #perform subset, cut and assignment
  dt2$slope[dt2$Vehicle.ID2==i]<- dt_slopez$slopez[cut(dt2$Time[dt2$Vehicle.ID2==i], breaks=breaks)]
}
```

Yes one for loop is used, but the time for loop should be insignificant to the time performing the sub-setting and assignment.  I am sure there are better ways.
It maybe possible to the dplyr package to perform a join??